# GKLocalPlayer loadRecentPlayersWithCompletionHandler returns empty array of recent players in iOS 10 GM

Tags: ios, game-center, ios10

I make a game with turn-based multiplayer in iOS 10.
I use iOS 10 GM version and Xcode 8 GM version.

I try to use new method to get list of recent players:

```
[player loadRecentPlayersWithCompletionHandler:^(NSArray<GKPlayer *> * _Nullable recentPlayers, NSError * _Nullable error) {
if (error)
    NSLog(@"Error!");
else {
    NSLog(@"No error!");
    NSLog(@"recentPlayers count= %d", [recentPlayers count]);
}
}];
```

I call the method right after local player has been authenticated.
When I call loadRecentPlayersWithCompletionHandler, I get no errors but empty array of recent players.

I see the list of finished games, where players recently played in Game Center App (iOS 9) and in GKTurnBasedMatchmakerViewController (in iOS 10).
But in iOS 10 loadRecentPlayersWithCompletionHandler returns empty array 
and page "Recent (players)" in GKTurnBasedMatchmakerViewController is empty too.

Do you use GKLocalPlayer.loadRecentPlayersWithCompletionHandler?

How to get list of recent players in iOS 10?